# Google apps script: где получить все горячие клавиши в редакторе проектов

Tags: google-apps-script

В частности меня интересует возможность переключиться между файлами проекта. В моем проекте например есть файл code.gs и code2.js, мне нужно переключиться между ними с использованием горячих клавиш.

Answer (score 0):

Только `[ESC] - [SHIFT]+[TAB]{10x+}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальные горячие клавиши видны в меню задач, если нажать `[F1]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]